# Is it possible to set up travis to run tests for several languages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, travis-ci, karma-runner

I have a rails project and am running tests for my JavaScript test ([Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/)) through [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io)

.travis.yml file

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.0.0
script:
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake --trace db:migrate test
  - karma start --single-run --browsers PhantomJS test/karma/config/unit.js
```

Travis fails saying it does not find karma. is there a way to define node_js as another language and install karma on the build VM?

Comment: FYI https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4090 indicates they will not support it any time soon.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It is [not possible yet](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/travis-ci/3pzCgvxWZAo) to have several languages on travis configuration file.

On the other hand, all environments [run node.js](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Runtimes). The following script does the trick:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.0.0
before_script:
  - npm install karma
script:
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake --trace db:migrate test
  - karma start --single-run --browsers PhantomJS test/karma/config/unit.js
```

Help found on [an old thread in a google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/travis-ci/l8DIsdRt5P4)

Comment: My [.travis.yml](https://github.com/OrangeTux/Goppetto/blob/develop/.travis.yml) with config to run both Go and Javascript tests.

Comment: Here's [how I run an **updated nodejs**](http://entulho.fiatjaf.alhur.es/guias/how-to-use-node-along-with-other-language-on-travis-ci/) installation along with any other language.

Answer (score 5):

K-Yo's answer got me moving in the right direction, but far short of success. Here is what I needed:

First in my .travis.yml:

```
language: ruby

rvm:
  - 2.1.1

before_script:
  - psql -c 'create database spokenvote_test;' -U postgres
  - cp config/database.travis.yml config/database.yml
  - rake db:test_prep
  - npm install karma
  - npm install karma-jasmine
  - npm install karma-coverage
  - npm install karma-phantomjs-launcher
  - npm install karma-coffee-preprocessor

script:
  - bundle exec rspec spec # basic for ruby
  - node_modules/karma/bin/karma start config/karma.conf.js --single-run --browsers PhantomJS
```

Then I also placed this code in my package.json, though I'm not sure if it was needed:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "karma": "~0.12",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.2",
    "karma-coverage": "~0.2.6",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.4",
    "karma-coffee-preprocessor": "~0.2.1"
},
```

Finally, I learned that Travis is case sensitive, so:

```
'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
```

in my karma.conf.js needed to be:

```
'bower_components/jQuery/dist/jquery.min.js',
```

Answer (score 2):

When the `language` key in `.travis.yml` is set to `node`, Travis will run `nvm install 0.12` at the beginning of the build. Similarly, for a Ruby project, Travis will run `rvm use 2.2.2 --install --binary --fuzzy` at the beginning of the build.

I've had success running both commands in a [Bash build](https://travis-ci.org/vinsonchuong/prototypical/builds/74675048)