# How to set up Travis CI with multiple languages

Tags: travis-ci

My project uses both nodejs and java

I tried starting off with a node_js build then installing java (since this is an npm module)

but the scripts to install java failed, plus I don't think there's a need to install it when there is a build with java that already exists.

should I start off with a java build then install node?

I'm trying this

```yml
language: java
  - oraclejdk8
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.10"
```

which ignores the first 2 lines it seems and builds a node_js build which has java 7
and my project uses java 8

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036259/how-to-write-travis-yml-if-my-project-deps-on-python-and-nodejs) for python

using

```yml
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.10"
java: oraclejdk8
```

but that didn't work

How can I add java 8?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456611/is-it-possible-to-set-up-travis-to-run-tests-for-several-languages

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used this `.yml`:

```
language: java
jdk:
    - oraclejdk8
node_js: "0.10"
install: "npm install"
script: "npm test"
```

Answer (score 122):

It seems to be possible now to run several languages in one .travis.yml file using the `jobs:include` feature.  As an example, my Github repo is arranged as follows:

```
project/ - top-level github directory
project/backend - Python backend
project/backend/tests - Python tests
project/android/AppName - Android app
project/ios/AppName - iOS app
```

Here is the .travis.yml, which runs tests in Python, Java, and Objective-C:

```
jobs:
  include:
    - language: python
      python: 2.7
      before_script:
        - cd backend/tests
      script:
        - python -m unittest discover

    - language: android
      dist: trusty
      jdk: oraclejdk8
      android:
        components:
          - tools
          - android-25
          - build-tools-25.0.3
      before_script:
        - cd android/AppName
      script:
        - ./gradlew build connectedCheck

    - language: objective-c
      os: osx
      osx_image: xcode8.3
      before_script:
        - cd ios/AppName
      script:
        - xcodebuild -workspace AppName.xcworkspace -scheme AppName
          -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=10.3' build test

notifications:
  email:
    - yourname@gmail.com
```

It seems you can build as many different configurations as you like using this feature, by treating each entry in the matrix as a top level config.  Of course, if you have any parameters you want to set that apply to all languages, you can do that at the top level, as I do here with the `notifications:email` section.

When it is all set up, then on each build, you get something like this. Boom.

[image]

Comment: This looked promising, but it fails the travis lint tool: http://lint.travis-ci.org

Comment: I can't speak to the lint tool, but I can say I've been using a setup like this for several months now, and it has worked perfectly.

Comment: I used this setup for python and nodejs. Instead of using `python: 3.5` to set the version, I used `python:\n - "3.5"` (notice these are two separate lines) as recommended in travis-ci's official page. The build is failed because travis tries to retrieve `python-["3.5"]` (notice the `[` and `"`). Do you know why that might be? The one-liner works.

Comment: Note: This DOES NOT WORK with multiple versions, e.g. `python: [3.5, 3.6]` because Travis only [takes the first array value](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Explicitly-included-jobs-inherit-the-first-value-in-the-array)

Comment: This should be the accepted solution! It works without any problems for one of my  repositories (c++, c, python, js and go all in one repo).

Comment: there's something odd here: the OP asked about setting multiple languages IN THE SAME BUILD, not about setting up multiple languages, one for each build.

Comment: To clarify: This solution does not work for running integration tests that rely on all languages?

Comment: @bluenote10 I believe that is an accurate statement.

Comment: @meisteg when using [the official travis lint tool](https://support.travis-ci.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002904174-Validating-travis-yml-files) it validates it fine. `$ travis lint ~/Desktop/test.yml
Hooray, /Users/nathanf/Desktop/test.yml looks valid :)`

Comment: It's now `jobs: include:` see the docs: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-matrix/

Comment: @makeworld - thanks!  updated accordingly

Answer (score 28):

On a Travis Java build environment, you can use `nvm` to manage [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) runtimes:

**.travis.yml**

```
language: java

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

env:
  - NODE_VERSION="0.12"

before_install:
  - nvm install $NODE_VERSION
```

If your Node version is very recent, you might have to update `nvm` too.

To update `nvm`, write this in your `.travis.yml`:

```
before_install:
  - wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/nvm.sh -O ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
  - source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
  - nvm install 5 # for Node v5
  - node --version
```

The above example shows how to first update to `nvm v0.31`, to then obtain `Node v5`.

Comment: That's my favorite solution.

Answer (score 13):

My project has a Python/Django backend and a JS/Vue frontend like below:

```
├── backend
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── tests                               
├── daemon                                                          
│   ├── frontend
│   │   ├── test
```

The idea is to run each test suite in a [matrix' job](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages/matrix-expansion/), one for Python/Django tests and the other for JS ones:

```
matrix:
  include:
    - language: python
      python: 
        - 3.4
      before_install:
        - cd backend/
      install: 
        - pip install -r requirements.txt
      script:
        - python manage.py test

    - language: node_js
      node_js:
        - 4.8
      before_install:
        - cd daemon/frontend
      install:
        - yarn install
      script:
        - yarn test

notifications:
  email: false
```

#### See also

- [TravisCI config](https://github.com/Coaxis-ASP/opt/blob/3b3a7dc8c0ff126d64cc4c6b42c0cbb0f999455a/.travis.yml) from my project and [TravisCI build](https://travis-ci.org/Coaxis-ASP/opt/builds/456005888)
- [How do Build Stages work?](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages/#how-do-build-stages-work) official doc

Answer (score 10):

You can't add multiple languages, which explains the behavior you are seeing, and the `node_js` setting will only be recognized in a node language project. What you can do is utilize the incorporated [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) in TravisCI.
For example, you can include

`- nvm install 0.10
- nvm use 0.10`

in your `before_install` section to download the latest v0.10.x release of node.

Comment: but I did manage to do it with the configuration file I self answered with

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-matrix/#using-different-programming-languages-per-job),

```
jobs:
  include:
    - language: python
      python: 3.8
      script:
      - python -c "print('Hi from Python!')"

    - language: node_js
      node_js: 12
      script:
      - node -e "console.log('Hi from NodeJS!')"

    - language: java
      jdk: openjdk8
      script:
      - javac -help
```

[Here](https://github.com/campos20/tnoodle/blob/c4cd8084645127c715293b4379e518da47271e5f/.travis.yml)'s a production example.