# Installing both Python and R for a Travis build?

Tags: python, r, travis-ci

I've been working on an R package which interfaces with Python via a simple server script and socket connections. I can test in on my own machine just fine, but I'd like to test it on a Travis build as well (I don't want to go through the effort of setting up a Linux VM). To do this I would need a Python install that I can pass the path to in my R package tests, and a port number to use.

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644586/how-to-set-up-travis-ci-with-multiple-languages) which suggests installing multiple Python builds is possible, but I'm not sure how to approach

1. Specifying the path(s) to the Python executable(s)
2. choosing a port number for the test. It should also be noted that the Python script I am using for the Python 'server' uses 'localhost'.

Is it possible to do what I want on Travis? *Should* I want to do this with Travis?

**EDIT** Here's my Travis config:

```
language: r
r:
  - release
  - devel
cache: packages
sudo: false

matrix:
  include:
    - python:2.7
    - python:3.6

# Be strict when checking our package
warnings_are_errors: true

# System dependencies for HTTP calling
r_binary_packages:
 - jsonlite
 - R6
```

And here is the example in my R package:

```
pypath = Sys.which('python') 
if(nchar(pypath) > 0) {
  py = PythonEnv$new(port = 6011, path = pypath)
  py$start
  py$running
  py$set(a = 5)
  py$get('a')
  py$stop
} else {
  message("No Python environment available")
}
```

My example definitely finds *a* Python path, but fails with the error

> Warning in socketConnection(port = self$port, open = "r+", blocking =
>   TRUE,  :   localhost:6011 cannot be opened
>
> Error socketConnection(port = self$port, open = "r+", blocking = TRUE,  :
>   cannot open the connection

I tested this with another port and same error occurs.

**EDIT 2**

I've also tried it with host `127.0.0.1` and `0.0.0.0` but no dice. According to the Travis documentation, this should work... perhaps an issue with the R container?

Comment: semi-VM suggestion but just want to put it out there: have you considered `dockerizing` your `python` server and then just exposing the appropriate ports to the `R` package script(s)? this way you can get more clean cut handling of all the python versions and deps

Comment: @salient Interesting, it looks like [Travis supports docker](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/) so this may be a solution. I'll look into it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a travis.yml I use for my pyrle package. It just installs R usinq the ubuntu package manager:

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.6"
install:
  - pip install cython pytest hypothesis
  - sudo apt-get install -y r-base
  - echo 'source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R"); biocLite("S4Vectors"); biocLite("GenomicRanges")' > install.R
  - python setup.py install

script:
  - py.test tests/
```

Another way is to install R through conda. Here is an example from the pyranges package:

```
# Stolen from http://conda.pydata.org/docs/travis.html
language: python
python:
  # We don't actually use the Travis Python, but this keeps it organized.
  - "3.6"
install:
  - sudo apt-get update
  # We do this conditionally because it saves us some downloading if the
  # version is the same.
  - wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh;
  - bash miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda
  - export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
  - hash -r
  - conda config --set always_yes yes --set changeps1 no
  - conda update -q conda
  - conda config --add channels bioconda
  - conda config --add channels r
  # Useful for debugging any issues with conda
  - conda info -a
  - conda create -q -n test-environment python=$TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION numpy scipy pandas pytest pytest-cov cython tabulate hypothesis bedtools # ray
  - source activate test-environment
  - python setup.py install # will install ncls
  - python --version
  - python -c 'import pandas as pd; print(pd.__version__)'
  - ls tests

script: py.test -v tests # verbose to see that tests run and so that travis does not time out on hypothesis tests
```

Comment: This is good to know. Although I want to start with an R build and install python, the basic approach of installing and configuring the Python environment should work in my case. I have since moved on from this project so I'm not going to go back and test if this all works, but I'll accept the answer since you demonstrate a working approach (although this may not resolve the sockets issue).

Comment: Thank you. This answers the title, but not the question completely. You are right.

Answer (score 2):

Your question title and question body are quite different.

### Regarding the python+R Question

Similarly to [The Unfun Cat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54630659/1483986) which uses travis to install python and installs R with apt, you can use travis for R and install python with apt:

```
language: r
install:
  - sudo apt-get install -y python2.7 python3.6
```

Note that travis also [has an apt addon](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/installing-dependencies/#adding-apt-packages) which makes your .yaml a bit cleaner (but arguably less portable).

```
language: r
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - python2.7
    - python3.6
```

The different python versions installed should be accessible to `Sys.which` as `python2.7` and `python3.6` instead of just "python". 
`which python` will return either the last version installed or else the last installed `python2*`.

---

### Regarding the networking question

There are a number of reasons a you may be unable to establish a connection. 
A common reason is that the port is already in use.
Port 6011 is sometimes used by the X window system ([ref](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=6011)), so it is possible a one of travis's services is using it.

Using [this reference on how to check for used ports](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-check-if-port-is-in-use-command/) you might try adding something like

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN | grep 6011
```

to your `travis.yaml` so you can see in the log if the port is used. 
You might also try a different unused port number in your script.

I did find [this github comment](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1304#issuecomment-305878517) referencing similar issues with R specifically; perhaps you can find more there.